# summernote editor dropdown is hiding behind another editor

Tags: css, html, text-editor, summernote

Steps to reproduce:

Go to the URL: https://summernote.org/examples/

Click on Font / Color dropdown

It's not overlapping / hiding behind the another editor

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome, I see the same issue on the multiple editor example on the summernote site in which the drop down menu is obscured by the toolbar of the editor below. Even though the z-index appears correct (1000 for dropdown and 500 for toolbar below), I was able to get it to display correctly by forcing the z-order to be 400 for the lower toolbar.

However, when I went to create a js fiddle with the workaround, it appeared to behave correctly.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nthzprq/)

HTML

```
<div class="multiple"><p>summernote 1</p></div>
<div class="multiple"><p>summernote 2</p></div>
<div class="multiple"><p>summernote 3</p></div>
<div class="multiple"><p>summernote 4</p></div>
<div class="multiple"><p>summernote 5</p></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.multiple').summernote();
});
```

I've been using summernote with multiple editors without issue (I just checked it was still working).

I don't have an answer as to what is broken on the example page but I also don't have enough reputation to post this partial answer/suggestion as a comment. If you post a jsfiddle with your issue, I may be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: set the z-index of **second** editor to be 0.

```
.note-editor {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but there are almost 7-8 editors so, for every editor I have to set a z-index higher than the previous one

Answer (score 1):

Add the below style in your page.

```
.note-toolbar {
    z-index: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried even other solutions but didn't work for me, or not fully.
Here's my solution:

```
if ($('.note-editor .note-toolbar').length) {
  var z_index = 900;
  $(".note-editor .note-toolbar").each(function(){
  $(this).css({'z-index': z_index});
  z_index--;
  });
}
```

Just copy and paste into your javascript (uses jQuery).
Loops through all toolbars on page and sets them z-index.